# How to change drag'n drop tooltip text in ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have two grids, where I defined drag and drop plugin like this:

```
plugins: {
        ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
        dragGroup: 'secondGridDDGroup',
        dropGroup: 'firstGridDDGroup'
    },
```

now, when I drag an item from one grid to another I see text "1 selected row" - how can I change this text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`dragText`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.DragDrop-cfg-dragText) config:

> The text to show while dragging.
>
> Two placeholders can be used in the text:
>
> - {0} The number of selected items.
> - {1} 's' when more than 1 items (only
>   useful for English).
>
> Defaults to: '{0} selected row{1}'

Comment: Is it possible to edit it dynamically, depending on which item I'm hovering over?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I suppose it is possible by overriding some methods of `Ext.grid.plugin.DragDrop`/`Ext.dd.DragZone`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set it dynamically using the onNodeOver event and something like:

```
dd.proxy.update("<span>Custom HTML here</span>");
```

Make sure you include a HTML tag as update() method calls setStyle.

See http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.dd.StatusProxy.html#method-update